# Error 401 (Unauthorized) llamando una API del clima

Tags: javascript

Estaba intentando hacer una página que muestre el clima actual basandose en la ubicación del usuario que accede a la misma. Pero en consola me aparece este error, que segun la pagina de la API se debe a que no esta ingresada correctamente la API_KEY. Note que al usar '$' no cambia de color en el editor que estoy usando (vscode) aun soy nueva en estas cosas agradeceria su ayuda ´

```
const API_KEY = 'd6aa53a3ce9de04b539de25fa54451b0';

const fetchData = position => {
    const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;
    fetch('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&appid=${API_KEY}')
        .then(response => response.json());
    //.then(response => console.log(response));

    console.log(position);
}
const onLoad = () => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(fetchData);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Estás usando comillas simples, por lo que javascript considera que es un string "normal". Es decir, no puedes añadir internamente interpolaciones. Para ello debes usar comillas invertidas:

```js
const textoNormal = 'Texto normal: ${5+4}';
const plantilla = `Texto normal: ${5+4}`;

console.log(textoNormal);
console.log(plantilla);
```

Comment: gracias! justo lo noté tambien :D encima me costo encontrar las comillas invertidas por mi teclado jajaja

Comment: Puedes marcar la respuesta tuya o mía como aceptada para que la pregunta quede como respondida

Answer (score 0):

Encontré por qué pasaba ^^, dentro del fetch el link tiene que estar entre dos tildes como estas `` ` ` `` y no entre unas comillas simples `' '`.Solved!